# HTTP/Request2.php not found even after installing HTTP_Request2

Tags: php, http, pear, azure-cognitive-services

I'm on a shared hosting plan on *NameCheap*. For *Microsoft Cognitive API* I need to use the **HTTP/Request2.php** file so I installed 2 PEAR packages

- HTTP_Request2
- Net_URL2

Still I'm getting the error **failed to open stream: No such file or directory**

In the cPanel it shows

> The administrator has enabled auto loading of “PHP Extensions and Applications Package” from “/home/XYZ/php”.
>   You will not need to modify your scripts.

Still it shows the error. How to solve the issue ?

PHP Code added

```
<?php
ini_set('include_path', '/home/XXXXXX/php');
require_once ' /home/XXXXXXX/php/HTTP/Request2.php';
$request = new Http_Request2('https://api.projectoxford.ai/face/v1.0/detect');
$url = $request->getUrl();
$headers = array(
'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' => '********************',
);
$request->setHeader($headers);
$parameters = array(
'returnFaceId' => 'false',
'returnFaceLandmarks' => 'false',
'returnFaceAttributes' => 'age',
 );
 $url->setQueryVariables($parameters);
 $request->setMethod(HTTP_Request2::METHOD_POST);
 $request->setBody("url:https://scontent.fbom1-2.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/10404393_1605697742978971_873608472502612270_n.jpg?oh=e10bf5b81b1f945594a1e0298cbae1e6&oe=583A5A85");
 try
 {
  $response = $request->send();
  echo $response->getBody();
 }
 catch (HttpException $ex)
 {
  echo $ex;
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: Can you provide some code and the full error message?

Comment: @Devon check it now

Comment: Not about your core question, but you'll need to fix a few issues after you straighten out the Request2 issue.

(1) SSL config needs tweaking:`$request->setConfig("ssl_verify_peer", false);`
(2) Body needs to be proper JSON: `$request->setBody("{\"url\":\"https://scontent....\"}");`

Answer (score 0):

Your include path is not setup correctly.

You should *not* need to modify the include path. If you do, *append* your changes to the existing include path and do not overwrite it.